# Converting html to the string

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

i am working with webview in my iphone and i want to pass the data in the form of html using the tags, so that i can add the text in the bold and italic and even the pictures in the form of string. So kindly help me out regarding this . Any help will be much appritiable.

Comment: What exactly you want? Do you want to form a HTML string and want to load that HTML string on WebView?

Comment: y u are using nsurl??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 205, 320, 150)];

 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ImageName"  ofType:@"png"];

 NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><b style='color:black'>Deleting your account will:<div style='margin-left:220px; margin-top:-27px'><img src='%@'></div></b><ul style='margin-left:-20px; margin-top:-1px; color:gray; font:Arial; font-size:12x'><li> write some line</li><li> write your line</li><li>write your line</li></ul></body></html>", filePath];

 // you can modified html string as per your need..

 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
 NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseUrl];
```